# cocos2D iOS 6 retina display

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios6, retina-display

I'm using cocos2D and TexturePacker. My game is working correctly with iOS < 6. Since I upgraded to iOS 6, my images are displayed 4 times bigger in retina. 
Looks like it is displaying retina images without compressing it by 4.

Comment: I have upgraded my cocos2d project that uses texture packer without any problems. Are you sure you have packed the correct sized files?

Comment: Since my game is working on iOS < 6, my guess is YES I packed the correct sized.

Comment: Try deleting the app from devices & simulator. In Xcode perform clean your project (Project -> Clean). Build again. This is just to be sure there are no remnants of a previous iOS 5 build that *might* interfere.

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be because of orientation. When I turn twice the device, it's returning to normal.
- In the appDelegate i'm working with a viewController that I added as a rootviewController.
- I added in the RootViewController the method : - supportedInterfaceOrientations and - shouldAutorotate

Comment: I have the same problem! what did you add to your methods? Thank you!