# iPhone5 and iOS6 combination creates display issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

My cocos2D app, Forever Afloat, works perfectly fine with all the combinations until you get to iPhone 5 and iOS6!
The app display is all stretched out so that you see only the lower left corner and the rest is off the screen.
Only until you force it to autorotate, does the app begin to display at proper dimensions...

My problems can also be found at this problem [cocos2D iOS 6 retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567239/cocos2d-ios-6-retina-display)
They asked the same question.
Any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: Well if you don't like use large screen just don't generate the file "Default-568h@2x.ong" or delete if exists (apple will maintain the dimentions like you run a iphone app on ipad), and about orientation, the engine of iOS6 change completely, you can create some warps to solve the orientation issues

Comment: I updated my question! please look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues within the AppDelegate regarding the order of calls that made the display all strange. All I did was move the initalization method to the top and it fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d uses image with image-hd.png and not image@2x.png
Check whether you are using @2x an replace by hd

Answer (score 0):

Use new version of cocos2d and here is image extension.

```
-wide.png for iphone 5
-widehd.png for iPhone 5 HD
-hd.png for iPhone HD 
-ipad.png for iPad. 
-ipadhd.png for iPad HD.
```